# regenerating url in cf9/Coldbox

Tags: url, coldfusion, url-routing, coldfusion-9, coldbox

Hi I am wondering if there is a way to regenerate the URL when any page is loaded in coldbox/CF9 when using event.buildLink ?

Currently I get http://cawksd05.codandev.local:8080/entries/editor when using event.buildlink.

But the correct url should have /index.cfm added to it as shown below:

/index.cfm/entries/editor

Is there a way to set this once and where does this get set as I am confused where to set this for all my pages so that /index.cfm gets added the the url prefix when I do an event.Buildlink.

Thanks
Faheem

// General Properties
 setUniqueURLS(false); 
 setAutoReload(false);

// Base URL
 if( len(getSetting('AppMapping') ) lte 1){
  setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/index.cfm");
 }
 else{
  setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/#getSetting('AppMapping')#/index.cfm");
 }

// Your Application Routes
 formatConstraints = {format="(xml|json)"};

addRoute(pattern="/api/:format/tasks/completed",handler="tasksAPI",action="list",constraints=formatConstraints,completed=true);
 addRoute(pattern="/api/:format/tasks",handler="tasksAPI",action="list",constraints=formatConstraints);
 addRoute(pattern="/api/:format?",handler="tasksAPI",action="invalid");

addRoute(pattern="/tasks/list/:status?",handler="tasks",action="index");
 addRoute(pattern=":handler/:action?");

Answer (score 4):

No, setnextevent is the ONLY method in 3.0 that should be used, the other ones setnextRoute and relocate() are now deprecated.

If you made a change to the Route.cfm, make sure you reinitialize the application for the changes to take effect.

index.cfm?fwreinit=1

Usually they forget to reinit the app if a change is made.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set the baseURL in the /config/Routes.cfm file

```
// Base URL
if( len(getSetting('AppMapping') ) lte 1){
    setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/index.cfm");
}
else{
    setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/#getSetting('AppMapping')#/index.cfm");
}
```

vs.

```
// Base URL
if( len(getSetting('AppMapping') ) lte 1){
    setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/");
}
else{
    setBaseURL("http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/#getSetting('AppMapping')#/");
}
```

Comment: hi Aaron thanks for that this is what I have set in my routes.cfm however when i use a setNextEvent or buildlink in another handler it does not add the base url including the index.cfm.

I will attach code for you to see.

Comment: Hi Aaron my code for that is added on the top of the page for routes.cfm.

Comment: also please note that if I add fwreinit=1 to my url that I am posting then the link works properly but without this the base url is not correct ie its without the index.cfm.

Comment: try setNextRoute() instead of setNextEvent.